# Binding ComboBox ItemsSource does not work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

This is kinda strange cause every example I found there says I'm doing things the right way yet I was unable to get my ComboBox binding to work in WPF.

I just created an empty WPF Application.

```
public List<string> myCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        myCollection = new List<string> {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"};
    }
```

And here is my xaml for this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myCollection}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,56,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" />
</Grid>
```

I have tried Binding myCollection, Binding Path=myCollection, I have tried with and without setting DataContext.
Nothing seems to be working.

I have run out of ideas and every example I find out there says this is the correct way and it should be working so thanks for any help i advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the datacontext after `InitializeComponent`

```
 InitializeComponent();          
 myCollection = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" };
 DataContext = this;
```

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for you, then make sure that you've added { get; set; } to the field.

Answer (score 5):

at the end of your constructor

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do that and this works I just wanted to make this using bindings

Comment: @RobertPorter then you should set the DataContext as suggested above!

Answer (score 0):

Sajeetheran answer works because the initialize of the XAML objects looks at the current state and binds to what is there *at that time* but will fail if one changes the property to something else. I would term that a **one-time** *work-around*.

> I just wanted to make this using bindings

For most WPF scenarios one wants to use the `INotifyPropertyChange` mechanision to allow for **dynamic** changes to be handled by the XAML bindings. If one wants to truly use the power of *bindings* it goes hand in hand with `INotifyPropertyChange`. Otherwise Dimitri's answer is just as valid as Sajeetharan's.

---

The binding does not know of the change because the reference of `myCollection`  does not notify the world of a change in status; hence the data doesn't get displayed.

To facilitate such notification the class used to hold the property needs to adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property `myCollection` needs to send a notify event. (*Note in your case its the main window which is technically workable, but in the MVVM paradigm one wants to seperate the view from the dat and a `ViewModel` class is used to hold the actual data and provide this notificaiton*).

```
 public MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then provide the event that will be subscribed to by the binding targets to the item on the `DataContext` :

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Then the mechanism to provide the change event.

```
/// <summary>
/// Raises the PropertyChanged event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed.</param>
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then provide the change for the `myCollection`

```
private List<string> _myCollection;

public List<string> myCollection
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
    set { _myCollection= value; OnPropertyChanged("myCollection"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> myCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {            
        myCollection = new List<string> {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"};
        DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent(); //-- call it at the end
    }
```

You have to `InitializeComponent` after assigning data context.