# ComboBox show -1 element when binded to itemsource WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a list like this:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>() { "1","2","3" };
```

And I link a combobox to it:

```
combobox1.ItemsSource = test;
```

When I start up the program, the combobox has the -1 element selected (empty). Now when I click it, it will show the 3 items from the list just fine. But when I select one of the items, I can't make it empty again. Any way to make it so that I pick the empty field again without editing the list?

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="573,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Normal" Height="32"/>
```

Comment: what do you have for the following in your code
`combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = ;
combobox1.SelectedValuePath` 
BInding in WPF and WinForms and WebForms are different.. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166772/binding-combobox-itemssource-does-not-work-in-wpf

Comment: Then set the `combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0` FYI `SelectedIndex is guaranteed to be unique, SelectedItem is not`

Comment: Not quite getting what u are saying, but no I cant edit the list. I want the list to stay intact.
There is nothing wrong with the binding to the list, it does show every object in the list, its just that I want to be able to deselect a item when i have selected one alredy. I could just make an button setting the combobox to selecteditem = -1, but i dont want to do it that way.

Comment: perhaps you need to read up on how to use `Binding Properly in WPF` this works just fine in WinForms and WebForms. what's your Xaml look like..

Comment: does us no good putting you code in comments update / edit your question and paste it there please

Comment: Sorry, pasted it in the question.

Comment: _"Any way to make it so that I pick the empty field again"_ -- setting `SelectedIndex` to `-1` isn't "picking an empty field". It's picking _no_ item at all. The `ComboBox` control simply does not have an option for the user to "unselect" anything in it. If you want the user to be able to do that, you need to provide the UI yourself and set the `SelectedIndex` property explicitly in your code. If you have problems doing that, please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

just type following code where you want to make empty selection.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not pick the empty value without this value was defined in the combo ItemsSource collection. However you can make your combo editable and then just delete selected value. Here is the code:
 1. Xaml code:

```
Window x:Class="ComboBoxSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:comboBoxSoHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:ComboBoxSoHelpAttempt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <comboBoxSoHelpAttempt:Null2StringConverter x:Key="Null2StringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <comboBoxSoHelpAttempt:ComboViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              IsEditable="True" SelectedValue="{Binding ComboSelectedValue}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" Width="150"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="Tomato"
        Text="{Binding ComboSelectedValue, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource Null2StringConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel></Window>
```

2. View model:

```
 public class ComboViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _comboSelectedValue;

    public ComboViewModel()
    {
        ComboItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboItem>
        {
            new ComboItem {Name = "Bob", Id = "1"},
            new ComboItem {Name = "Joe", Id = "2"},
            new ComboItem {Name = "John", Id = "3"},
            new ComboItem {Name = "Roi", Id = "4"},
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ComboItem> ComboItems { get; set; }

    public string ComboSelectedValue
    {
        get { return _comboSelectedValue; }
        set
        {
            _comboSelectedValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

3. Model:

```
 public class ComboItem:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _id;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

4. Converter code:

```
public class Null2StringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? "Null" : value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

5. BaseObservableObject is the simple implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

6. How its look like: [image: selected] and [image: deleted]

I'll be glad to help if there will be problems with my code.
Regards,